# click event for a href tag (which is created dynamically)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a click event for a href tag  (which is created dynamically and added by .html atributes to my result div).

What I have done so far:

```
$("#upload-div").on("a[href='#Sixty']",'click',function(){
   alert('test'); 
});
```

and

here you see my HTML which is added dynamically:

```
  <button type='button' class='btn btn-info dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>\n\
    Font Selection <span class='caret'></span>\n\
  </button>\n\
  <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>\n\
      <li><a href='#Arial'>Default(Arial)</a></li>\n\
      <li class='divider'></li>\n\
    <li><a href='#Arial'>Arial</a></li>\n\
    <li><a href='#Sixty'>Sixty</a></li>\n\
    </ul>\n\
</div>   \n\
```

But it does not work; did I miss anything?
If you need more clarification, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: The first param of `on()` is the event, the second is the selector.

Comment: JAson you were so fast man; if you like go ahead and post it as an answeer so I can mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using event delegation, the first param of on() is the event, the second is the selector:

```
$("#upload-div").on('click', 'a[href="#Sixty"]', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the first param is the event like:

```
$("#upload-div").on('click','a[href="#Sixty"]',function(){
   alert('test'); 
});
```

You also want to make sure that upload-div is loaded when the above code is called.

Comment: ok, you may want to get Jason to post it as an answer, so you can mark it as solved.